# Google Play Saved Games - API Limit Reached

Tags: android, google-play-games

One of our released live games uses Google Play Saved Games, which in the last 2 weeks or so has appeared to stopped working correctly with a lot of users seeing failed attempts at loading their saves games. Before that it has been working fine since release earlier this year.

We’re receiving the following error messages when we debug:

403 Reason:[rateLimitExceeded] Location:[]

Which implies we are hitting a quota or rate limit.

The google cloud quotas page suggests we’re well within our quota limits, so we’re not sure how to proceeed, and the google support ticket system offered no help even unfortunately...

Anyone  had similar issues, or be able to provide any insight into what we might be doing wrong? The obvious thing is to cut down on upload attempts, but we're clearly within the limits, so we want to know what could potentially be going wrong before attempting wishful fixes.

Thanks, appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 0):

You probably exceed the quota limits you set before: this is either the daily billable or the limit on the request characters per second. You can review your application's daily quota for the [Play Games SDK](https://developers.google.com/games/services/quota) by visiting your project in the Google Developers Console.

To change the usage limits or request an increase to your quota.

- Go to the Google Developers Console "https://console.developers.google.com/".
- Select a project.
- On the left sidebar, expand APIs & auth.
- Click APIs.
- Click the name of an activated API you're interested in.
- Near the top of the info page for the API, click Quota.

If you have the billing enabled, just click Quota and it will take you to the quota page where you can view and change the quota-related settings.
If not, clicking [Quota](https://developers.google.com/games/services/quota#managing_your_daily_quota) shows information about any free quota and limits that apply to the API.

You can set the maximum number of calls a user can make per second, to help ensure that an abusive player doesn't use up all of your application's quota. To learn more about capping usage, see the Google Developers Console documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment here, it looks like we're within our quota though. I've requested a higher quota anyway, but it could be weeks before we here from them. The only thing we've changed is updated to the latest Google Play SDK.